# How to shuffle a stream using the Stream API?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I decided to take the functional approach in generating a string or random characters, so far I came up with this, it should perform better than boxing and then using a `StringJoiner` as collector:

```
Random random = new Random();
String randomString = IntStream.concat(
        random.ints(8, 'a', 'z'),
        random.ints(8, 'A', 'Z')
)
        .collect(
                StringBuilder::new,
                (sb, i) -> sb.append((char)i),
                (sb1, sb2) -> sb1.append(sb2)
        ).toString();
```

I want to generate a stream of 16 characters, ranging from a-z or A-Z, the problem I have is that I do not know how to shuffle both streams.

I know that I am using `IntStream.concat` here,  which will simply concatenate both streams, I'm looking for either of the following:

- A static operator like `IntStream.concat` that does the shuffling when merging the streams.
- A stream operator like `sorted()`.

Both ways are viable in my opinion, however I am especially intrigued by how to make an operator alike `sorted()`. The key point here is that it is an operator that is stateful as it needs to see the whole stream before it can operate, is there a way to inject a stateful operator in a stream sequence?

So far the operations, excluding the needed work to shuffle them, seem to not be appropiate for a functional approach in Java 8.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are thinking too twisted

```
Random random = new Random();
String randomString=random.ints(16, 0, 26*2).map(i->(i>=26? 'a'-26: 'A')+i)
  .collect(StringBuilder::new,
           StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
  .toString();
```

Since you already have a source of random values there is no point in calling for a shuffle function (which would not work very well with *streams*).

Note that you also could define the allowed chars in a `String` explicitly and select them using:
`random.ints(16, 0, allowed.length()).map(allowed::charAt)`

Similar pattern applies to selecting from a random access `List`.

---

Update: If you want to have code clearly showing the two ranges nature of the allowed characters you can combine your `Stream.concat` approach with the `char` selection solution described above:

```
StringBuilder allowed=
  IntStream.concat(IntStream.rangeClosed('a', 'z'), IntStream.rangeClosed('A', 'Z'))
    .collect(StringBuilder::new,
             StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append);
String randomString=random.ints(16, 0, allowed.length()).map(allowed::charAt)
  .collect(StringBuilder::new,
           StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
  .toString();
```

(Note: I replaced `range`  with `rangeClosed` which I suspect to match your original intentions while it does not do what `Random.ints(…, 'a', 'z')` would do).

Comment: It does unfortunately get rid of the clear `'a' - 'z'` and `'A' - 'Z'` ranges.

Comment: That's not shuffling. This allows for duplicates. Shuffling implies the original elements are preserved, just not their order.

Comment: @Mark Jeronimus: this is not shuffling, but as explained in the answer, shuffling is not the right tool for solving the actual task of the question, which is to generate a random `String` using the `Stream` API. The random `String` might have duplicates before the shuffling and so might to `String` created by the alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not as elegant as you hoped for but it works:

```
final Random random = new Random();
String randomString = IntStream.concat(random.ints(8, 'a', 'z'+1), random.ints(8, 'A', 'Z'+1))
    .collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb, i) -> {
      int l = sb.length();
      if (l == 0) {
        sb.append((char) i);
      } else {
        int j = random.nextInt(l);
        char c = sb.charAt(j);
        sb.setCharAt(j, (char) i);
        sb.append(c);
      }
    }, (sb1, sb2) -> sb1.append(sb2)).toString();
System.out.println(randomString);
```

Alternatively you could do this:

```
final String randomString = random.ints(100, 'A', 'z' + 1)
        .filter(i -> i <= 'Z' || i >= 'a').limit(16)
        .collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb, i) -> sb.append((char) i), 
                StringBuilder::append).toString();
```