# Alpha Numeric Random Number Sequence [5-digit or 6-digit or any digit] generation

Tags: java, random, java-stream

Hi I am trying to generate a 5 digit random number which is alpha numeric in nature. I am doing both with without using Streams.

**CODE**

```
public class AlphaRandom {
    
    private static final String ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    static final Random random = new Random();
    
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int length = 5;
        String seq = randomAlphaNumeric(length);        
        System.out.println("Random Number Normal  : " +seq);        
        IntStream.range(0,1).forEach(i->System.out.println("Random Number Streams : " +generateRandomString(random, length)));
        
    }
    
    // Using Streams
    private static String generateRandomString(Random random, int length){
        return random.ints(48,122)
                .filter(i-> (i<57 || i>65) && (i <90 || i>97))
                .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
                .limit(length)
                .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append)
                .toString();
    }
    
    // Normal 
    public static String randomAlphaNumeric(int count) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();    
        while (count-- != 0) {  
            int character = (int)(Math.random()*ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.length()); 
            builder.append(ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.charAt(character)); 
        }   
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

**Sample Outputs** :

```
Random Number Normal  : VYAXC
Random Number Streams : LdBN6

Random Number Normal  : 2ANTT
Random Number Streams : hfegc

Random Number Normal  : JWK4Y
Random Number Streams : 8mQXK
```

But I am unable to generate the sequence always starting with a `UpperCase` only.
Can someone help me out.

Comment: Well, you could use 2 strings and concatenate those or combine 2 streams. However, I'd suggest you consider whether using streams for this would _really_ be the best option in terms of performance, readability, debugging etc. - In your "normal" approach you could limit the character be selected from the uppercase character range only (for that I'd probably replace the `while(...)` with something like `for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)` though).

Comment: @Thomas : okk thanks .. let me try.

Comment: `ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";`

Comment: There’s no advantage in `random.ints(48,122) .filter(i-> (i<57 || i>65) && (i <90 || i>97))` instead of `random.ints('0', 'z') .filter(i-> (i<'9' || i>'A') && (i <'Z' || i>'a'))` Further, you’re using the wrong bounds. It must be `.ints('0', 'z' + 1)`, to include `z` and you have to use `<=` and `>=` to include `'9'`, `'A'`, `'Z'`, and `'a'`. But why not follow the logic of your non-stream approach and use `random.ints(length, 0, ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.length()) .map(ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING::charAt) .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append) .toString()`

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49937398/2711488) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24065048/2711488) for an inspiration.

Comment: @Holger : Thanks ! Appreciate your inputs.  I will try to execute your approaches as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use `RandomStringUtils` from the apache library to do this. The reason to do this is less code and I believe better readability of the code.

This is my code which can do the required thing

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

public class GenerateRandomString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int keyLength = 5; // Number of character allowed as per requirement
        String randomAlphanumeric = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(keyLength);
        System.out.println("randomAlphanumeric generated is " + randomAlphanumeric);
        String upperCaseRandom = randomAlphanumeric.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + randomAlphanumeric.substring(1);
        System.out.println("upperCaseRandom generated is " + upperCaseRandom);
    }
}
```

It would generate the following output:

```
randomAlphanumeric generated is m8OiR
upperCaseRandom generated is M8OiR
```

I am making the first character to uppercase as required by question using the substring method.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is that before to return your string (once you have generated it), you take the first letter in order to apply `toUpperCase` and on the remaining chars, apply `toLowerCase`. Also, if in the future you will need to generate longer strings, you can use the same method without changing anything.

Summering what we'll do is:

```
public static String manipulate (String rand){
    String c = rand.substring(0,1); // where rand is the random alphanumeric generated by your methods, we pick the first char
    c = c.toUpperCase(); //we make it upperCase
    String split = rand.substring(1); //we get the remaining of the string starting from position 1
    split = split.toLowerCase(); //let's apply lowercase on the remaining
    String result = c+split; //join again
    return result;
}
```

Full Code:

```
package test;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class AlphaRandom {

    private static final String ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    static final Random random = new Random();


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int length = 5;
        String seq = randomAlphaNumeric(length);
        System.out.println("Random Number Normal  : " +seq);
        IntStream.range(0,1).forEach(i->System.out.println("Random Number Streams : " +generateRandomString(random, length)));

    }

    public static String manipulate (String rand){
        String c = rand.substring(0,1); // where rand is the random alphanumeric generated by your methods, we pick the first char
        c = c.toUpperCase(); //we make it upperCase
        String split = rand.substring(1); //we get the remaining of the string starting from position 1
        split = split.toLowerCase(); //let's apply lowercase on the remaining
        String result = c+split; //join the again
        return result;
    }

    // Using Streams
    private static String generateRandomString(Random random, int length){
        String rand =  random.ints(48,122)
                .filter(i-> (i<57 || i>65) && (i <90 || i>97))
                .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
                .limit(length)
                .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append)
                .toString();
        return manipulate(rand);
    }

    // Normal
    public static String randomAlphaNumeric(int count) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while (count-- != 0) {
            int character = (int)(Math.random()*ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.length());
            builder.append(ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.charAt(character));
        }
        return manipulate(builder.toString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Random Number Normal  : Mwwsz
Random Number Streams : Q1fqk
```